# investing - where to trade online? (Greek citizen)

Tags: online-banking, starting-out-investing, greece

I wanted to know if you could help me a bit because online searches didn't bring back many results (at least what I was looking for, ie non-Greek banks, etc).

Can you recommend any sites where EU-citizens in general or Greek citizens in particular can open an account for investing/trading (stocks, forex, mutual funds, etc)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You will likely need to open an account in another EU country, like a broker operating out of France, Britain or Germany, to get the best options.  If you are comfortable using an english language site and interface, I highly recommend [Interactive Brokers](http://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk) as they let you trade in many markets simultaneously, have simple currency conversion, and great tools.  But, they are geared toward active traders so you might be better with a more retail oriented broker if you are new to trading stocks.

There are many options.  Here is a list to start with:

[image: online brokers by area]

Comment: In the UK: iWeb ShareDealing (I use them), Bestinvest, SippDeal, Selftrade...

Answer (score 0):

The Greek [Piraeus Bank](http://www.piraeusbankgroup.com/) offers such services for trading stocks in Athens Stock Exchange (ASE) and in addition 26 other markets including NASDAQ, NYSE and largest European ones ([full list](http://www.piraeusbank.gr/el/idiotes/trapezikes-ypiresies/kathimerines-synallages/xrimatistiriakes-ypiresies), in Greek).

Same goes for [Eurobank](http://www.eurobankequities.gr/idiotes/private/hlektronikes-synallages.aspx) with a list of 17 international markets and the ability to trade bonds.

[BETA Securities](http://www.betasecurities.com/en/) has also an online platform, but I think it's only for ASE.

Some other banks (like [National Bank of Greece](http://www.nbg.gr/)) do have similar online services, but are usually restricted to ASE.